# What is the difference between 认为 and 以为?

Tags: synonyms

They both mean "to think" or "to consider". Is there a usage difference between the two?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`以为` carries with it the nuance of thinking or considering something mistakenly.

> 我以为你们已经分手了。 - I thought you had already broken up (but it seems you're still together.)

`认为` doesn't have any such connotation and can be used generally to mean "to think," "to consider."

> 我认为他是我最重要的朋友。 - I consider him to be my most important friend.

Answer (score 5):

Putting it simple:

认为 - think or consider

以为 - thought or considered (but I was wrong).